# How to I focus on an element after it is added in CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor

I am using CKEditor 4.4.1 with `CKEDITOR.config.enterMode` set to `ENTER_P`.

I am adding a new paragraph programmatically and then moving the cursor to the new element:

```
var element = new CKEDITOR.dom.element('p', editor.document);
element.appendBogus();

var range = editor.createRange();

range.setStartAt(referenceNode, CKEDITOR.POSITION_AFTER_END);
range.collapse(true);

editor.editable().insertElement( element, range );

range.moveToElementEditStart( element );
editor.getSelection().selectRanges( [ range ] );
```

This creates and inserts the element in the correct place. However, for some reason, the cursor is not placed in the newly created element.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Small correction - you should not use editor.editable().insertElement, but rather [`editor.insertElement`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-insertElement). Also, it should be enough if you add this button to focus manager or prevent default action of `mousedown` on it.

Comment: @Reinmar I have changed my implementation to use `editor.insertElement`. Is there any reason why `editor.editable().insertElement()` should not be used?

Comment: Mainly because `editor` object keeps the main APIs and it passes the control to other objects. But usually it also does a little bit more - e.g. it fires the `insertElement` event which other components can listen to and react. Most of editor methods work thanks to events and many components use them.

Answer (score 0):

Because I was using a elements that were not part of CKEditor to trigger the insertion, the CKEditor instance was losing focus.

In addition to the code above, I also had to do `editor.focus()`.